# Get JSON respone that always change every 10 second (realtime vehicle location)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, socket.io

I want to make project about real time vehicle location, and i want to make a demo of vehicle that always change location in map every 10 second.
I just learn about REST API, how can I get response from endpoint that always change every 10 second in real time without refreshing browser

example ( 2 car moving)
GET /app/vehicle/location
res :

```
[{ 
       "name":"vehicle1",
       "latitude" : "xxxx123",
       "longitude" : "xxxxx213",
       "number" : 1
       },
       { 
       "name":"vehicle2",
       "latitude" : "xxxx645",
       "longitude" : "xxxxx534",
       "number" : 1
       }
      ]
```

and in 10 second the response is change in longitude latitude,

```
res : [{ 
       "name":"vehicle1",
       "latitude" : "xxxx543",
       "longitude" : "xxxxx533",
       "number" : 2
       },
       { 
       "name":"vehicle2",
       "latitude" : "xxxx458",
       "longitude" : "xxxxx239",
       "number" : 2
       }
      ]
```

the response is from vehicle table order by number

after searching for I while, i think i can make this using websocket (socket.io) or firebase,

please help

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for that. You use JavaScript **setInterval()**  method.

Expample:

```
setInterval(() => { 
  // Call your API endpoint here
}, 100)
```

Hope it will help you. :)